# SSH doens't show the latest character typed

Tags: ssh

I can connect via ssh without a problem (Ubuntu 10.10 the client, 10.04 on the server) but when I'm logged in, I can't see the latest character I have typed into the terminal.

For instance, when I type "cd /home/myhome", I only see "cd /home/myhom" in the terminal. If I hit return, the results aren't displayed unless I hit return a second time.

Other than that the connection seems fine, though I do see many sshd zombie processes kicking around.

Comment: is the command "correct" after you hit return twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try emptying your prompt, ot might contain a delete character or some other strange escape sequence.

```
export PS1="> "
```

You can also check your $TERM variable, and the output of `stty -a` for problems.

Comment: No joy. The session starts normally and I can type fine, but after a few commands it starts dropping characters. Thank you for the suggestion though :)